# Validação com ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal estou com problema,preciso que o atributo codigo(do meu banco de dados) tem quer ter posição maior de 4 números e  com atributo valor não pode conter o valor menor que 0.

Tentei usar o   [StringLength(4)] porem quando ele executa da erro porque só pode usar caractere ,procurei alguma soluções mas até agora nada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Robson, bem vindo ao Stack OverFlow em Português. 
Para melhor compreendermos, será que poderia colocar o código ao invés da imagem? Qual versão do [tag:asp.net-mvc] você está utilizando?
Aproveitando, no site existe o [tour]. Dê uma passadinha lá quando tiver um tempinho para entender melhor o site :p

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda,minha versão é o ASP MVC 5 ,vou dar uma olhada sim.

Answer (score 0):

```
[MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {1} caracteres")]
```

Comment: No caso no minlength você põe 5.

Comment: Valeu cara,deu certo e imaginar que era só isso hahahhaha

Comment: Só que ai apareeceu esse erro ,System.InvalidCastException: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Int32' no tipo 'System.Array'.

Comment: Você quer que o código tenha pelo menos 4 dígitos é isso? O o valor tem que ser no mínimo 4? O que você pode fazer é criar uma partial class porque ao fazer na própria tt você vai perder o que digitou. Os arquivos gerados automaticamente com o T4 são apagados ao gerar novamente. Você pode criar uma classe a parte e então adicionar uma propriedade string para isso. Ou então usar uma expressão regular:

Comment: Consegui,muito obrigado usei essa Regular Expressão( @"\d{4}$")

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Comment: Ok obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss